# MVC4 w/Web API and EF5. Why so many contexts?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am just learning MVC, Web API and Entity Framework.

I created an MVC 4 Web App w/Web API in VS 2012. Under Models, I right clicked Add and then ADO.NET Entity Data Model. This allowed me to create the database layout I wanted. I then right clicked and selected Generate Database from Model.

Everything seemed to work correctly - at least the new database was created and I see a class for each of my tables under the ...Model.tt that gets created. Under ...Model.Context.tt I have a ...Model.Context.cs containing:

```
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<State> States { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

When I tried Web API at /api/user/ I received an error of resource not found. So I thought I might need to create controllers? ApiControllers? Which is what I did, one controller for each of my tables - UserController, MessageController, etc. Creating each of these also required specifying a Data context class - I selected to create a new one which I think might have been wrong.

The problem I am seeing now is that I have all of these classes with a base class of DbContext that are created. I just noticed each one had a connectionstring line added in web.config. :S

I'm sure this isn't right - all of these tables are in the same database and so only one connection is needed.

From what I've documented, can anyone tell me where I went wrong? Should I have created a controller for each table?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite clear on what you mean by "all of these classes".  Do you mean you have instances of your Database context in each of your controllers?  Or do you literally mean you have created a UsersDataContext and a MessagesDataContext.. etc..?

You should only have one DbContext in your app, although you will have many instances of it.  I'm not sure where you went wrong, as I know of no place where you it asks you to create multiple contexts.. so I don't get where you said "I selected to create a new one".

Whether or not you create a controller for each table depends on many factors.  Controllers should be centered around your functionality.  Such as an Account controller, or a Home Controller, or a Product controller.. which may map to tables in some cases, but is really oriented around your functional needs.

Comment: Since /api/user/ didn't work, I created an ApiController by right clicking on Controllers, and Add new Controller. The dialog that comes up wants to know a Template, I chose API Controller with read/write acctions, using Entity Framework. Then, for Model Class I saw my User class and chose it. For the Data context class I chose the top item of the dropdown - New data context because I saw nothing else I could use in the list.

Comment: @rwkiii - Your Primary data context should be listed in that dialog, you should be using that, not creating a new one.

Comment: You are right Mystere. I created a new project. When I created the controllers I used the same context for all of them and it worked. Thank you for your help!